# ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 22: No database selected, when restoring database using deitch/mysql-backup

Tags: mysql, docker-compose

I am setting up mysql database restore using docker image (deitch/mysql-backup).

I have created a docker-compose file where I have implemented a service for mysql database restore using docker image deitch/mysql-backup.

```
  restore:
    image: databack/mysql-backup
    volumes:
     - ./dbRestore/Dump20190824.sql.tar.gz:/dbr/Dump20190824.sql.tar.gz
    environment:
     - DB_RESTORE_TARGET=/dbr/Dump20190824.sql.tar.gz
     - DB_USER=root
     - DB_PASS=root
     - DB_PORT=3306
     - DB_DUMP_DEBUG=true
     - DB_SERVER=mysql
    depends_on:
      - mysql
```

While I am running docker-compose, I am getting this error-
`restore_1  | ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 22: No database selected`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with a docker-compose service configuration which fulfill my requirement.

```
  backup:
    image: databack/mysql-backup
    restart: always
    user: "0"
    volumes:
      - ./dbBackup:/dbb
    environment:
      - DB_DUMP_TARGET=/dbb
      - DB_USER=root
      - DB_PASS=root
      - DB_PORT=3306
      - DB_NAMES=karakira
      - DB_DUMP_FREQ=720
      - DB_DUMP_BEGIN=+90
      - DB_SERVER=mysql
    depends_on:
      - django
```